# Device specific screen capturing on android

Tags: android, screen, capture

We need to find a way to capture Android screen, without using any external software, which will work on a non-rooted phone.

My research shows that there is no way to do that. In any way, you should have root permissions, to be able to capture device's screen.

Further research, however, shows, that there is a way for limited number of devices, to do that, without having root privileges. As a proof I can bring following application on Android  market: Screenshot UX.

It claims, that app doesn't need root permissions for capturing screen on following devices:

- Gallaxy series (S,S2,...)
- HTC phones (Sensation, ...)
- Motorola (Atrix, ...).
- LG Optimus series (G2X, ...)

Some say, that Tegra devices support that also.

Could anyone point on some documentation, at least on specific devices, so we can at least support HTC phones, for example.

EDIT: For now we are trying to use "/system/bin/screencap", with no success on emulator though.
Does availability of taking screenshots on some certain devices just means that they allow to use "/system/bin/screencap" or read directly from /dev/graphics/fb0?

Or they give some API for taking screenshots?

Thanks.

Comment: Some of these devices have an unsecured command line tool left by the system or graphics vendor which enables the DDMS screenshot in circumstances where Google's original raw framebuffer method was incompatible with the hardware, and its newer methods not yet implemented.  Such a tool may stand out by name or by group ownership and sticky bits; though if it's not special in such security parameters it may indicates an undocumented and unsecured API which you could reverse engineer and utilize from your own code.

Comment: so is there anyway we can test it? i mean some examples, guides, etc. we have some devices on the list, on which we can run the tests.

Comment: If you are not capable of doing your own investigations, then a business area based on temporary, device specific oddities is not one you should try to be in.  Even if you are, it's a pretty unstable idea, as these phones will becomes obsolete and replaced in the marketplace with ones that are either better locked down, or at least have different mistakes which you will have to identify and utilize.

Comment: Chris, could you please give an answer to edited version? We understand, risks of writing app for that devices, also we understand, that the features presented in that devices could be locked down or give product with lot of bugs. Nevertheless, we need to do that. In the question I have wrote what investigation was done, so I think that we **are** capable of doing own investigations.

Comment: You are going to need to do your own investigations of the possibilities I described for **each** device of interest, as this is entirely about the unique methods of distinct hardware versions, likely none of which are sufficiently matched by the emulator.  If you are going to operate in the "not recommended" area of Android development, you need to be prepared to look at devices in that level of detail yourself, rather than expecting to find the answers online.

Answer (score 0):

Screen capturing is an old and much discussed topic on android.
Over the last years few major options developed:

1. Running screencap on rooted devices, But you already know this.
2. Running screencap and siginging your application with system certificate:

There is a permission READ_FRAME_BUFFER but you only can obtain it when your apps are signed as system application.

3. Using all sort of ADB tricks, but most of them use screencap and AFAIK require you to have the device connected to a PC.

[But Since Android 5 things have changed.](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html)

> Android 5.0 lets you add screen capturing and screen sharing
>   capabilities to your app with the new android.media.projection APIs.
>   This functionality is useful, for example, if you want to enable
>   screen sharing in a video conferencing app.
>
> The new createVirtualDisplay() method allows your app to capture the
>   contents of the main screen (the default display) into a Surface
>   object, which your app can then send across the network. The API only
>   allows capturing non-secure screen content, and not system audio. To
>   begin screen capturing, your app must first request the user’s
>   permission by launching a screen capture dialog using an Intent
>   obtained through the createScreenCaptureIntent() method.

The devices you mentioned are quite old and I doubt that they got an official update to android 5, this leaves you with the 2nd option.