# Android screen capture on rooted device

Tags: android, screenshot, rooted-device

Screen capture on rooted device
I want to capture screen of an android device rooted using APK.
I tried

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/screencap -p " + path + ”/file.png ”);
```

This command is working fine but it is too slow.
Then I tried using second option

```
View content = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache());
OutputStream fout = null;
File imageFile = new File(_path,"ScreenImage.png");
try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But in this I am getting view of my application not current screen.
I am is to capture screen shots an make video out of them I am using FB0 to make video but make problem is to capture screen with speed of 8 frames per second

Please suggest solution for speeding this process. resolution is not problem it can be of poor quality.

Comment: Is this code inside Activity or Service?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242131/device-specific-screen-capturing-on-android

Answer (score 1):

Since your device is rooted, take a look at framework hide api SurfaceControl's screenshot method. Didn't test if it's fast enough.

```
public static Bitmap screenshot(int width, int height) {
    // TODO: should take the display as a parameter
    IBinder displayToken = SurfaceControl.getBuiltInDisplay(
            SurfaceControl.BUILT_IN_DISPLAY_ID_MAIN);
    return nativeScreenshot(displayToken, width, height, 0, 0, true);
}
```

The normal step to take screenshot is, intercepting screenshot combination key in PhoneWindowManager, then connect to a screenshot service in systemui, this service will call method SurfaceControl.screenshot to take the screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this articles:

http://android-chirag.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/video-recording-example-in-android.html

http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html

Comment: I want to record phone screen not use camera